# PlistBuddy - adding array items works in terminal but not in bash script

Tags: xcode, bash, plist, plistbuddy

I try to manipulate my Info.plist file using `plistbuddy` by adding custom fonts array field by script. The commands execute successfully in terminal (both: array entry is created and entries are added):

```
luka$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy testing.plist
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: testing.plist
Command: Add UIAppFonts array
Command: Add UIAppFonts: string test
Command: Add UIAppFonts: string Test2
Command: Save
Saving...
```

**This produces nice plist file, as expected:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>test</string>
        <string>Test2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But the same commands fail while executing in bash script (`test.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash
PLISTBUDDY="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c"
FILE="./test.plist"
$PLISTBUDDY "Add UIAppFonts array" $FILE
FF_CUSTOM_FONTS="Font_a.otf,Font_b.otf"
set -f; IFS=,
    FONT_INDEX=0
    for CUSTOM_FONT in $FF_CUSTOM_FONTS
        do
            PLIST_COMMAND="Add UIAppFonts: string $CUSTOM_FONT"
            echo "executing: $PLIST_COMMAND"
            $PLISTBUDDY $PLIST_COMMAND $FILE
            FONT_INDEX=$((FONT_INDEX+1))
        done
set =f; unset IFS
```

In this case, only array is created, but adding entries fail. I only get not that much descriptive error:

```
luka$ ./test.sh
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: ./test.plist
executing: Add UIAppFonts: string Font_a.otf
./test.sh: line 12: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c: No such file or directory
executing: Add UIAppFonts: string Font_b.otf
./test.sh: line 12: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c: No such file or directory
```

**Produces this (only array, no entries):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Why does that happen and why only with commands adding entries to an array?I use `plistbuddy` in many other places (in bash scripts) and commands like setting, adding and deleting simple fields all work just fine.

I am not that good in scripting, so most probably I am missing some kind of escaping or other bash specific detail.

Comment: It fails in the loop because you did `IFS=,` (split variables on commas), but then try to run a command with `$PLISTBUDDY` which is separated by spaces. Rewrite it to use arrays instead, so you don't need any splitting

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am getting the same strange array as you do:

```
<array/>
```

instead of:

```
<array>
</array>
```

and the actual array contents is not written either. I am messing around with the network config on Mac and iOS:

```
/private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

Mac (or iOS symlink):
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

seems scutil can't change proxy config, can't find "networksetup" for iOS and the iOS GUI settings don't allow to define exceptions to bypass, I want to bypass "192.168/16", so the proxy is not used for intrAnet. So PlistBuddy says:

```
Add <Entry> <Type> [<Value>]
```

I am doing exactly that!:

```
PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList array 192.168/16" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

and all I am getting is this strange array (above). Turns out this has to be separated in two steps:

```
PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList array" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList:0 string 192.168/16" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

Here's my code in case you are interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

# first array item: ethernet
# second array item: wifi
# afterwards: CommCenter

var1=`PlistBuddy -c "Print CurrentSet" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

var1=${var1/#\/Sets\/}

echo Set: $var1

if [ -n "$1" ] && [ $1 == add ]; then
    echo ADD

    var2=`PlistBuddy -c "Print Sets:$var1:Network:Global:IPv4:ServiceOrder:1" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

    echo Key: $var2

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPEnable integer 1" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPPort integer 89" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPProxy string 192.168.0.21" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSEnable integer 1" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSPort integer 89" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSProxy string 192.168.0.21" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

elif [ -n "$1" ] && [ $1 == remove ]; then
    echo REMOVE

    var2=`PlistBuddy -c "Print Sets:$var1:Network:Global:IPv4:ServiceOrder:1" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

    echo Key: $var2

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPEnable" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPPort" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPProxy" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSEnable" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSPort" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

    PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:HTTPSProxy" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
else
    echo BYPASS

    for i in $(seq 0 1)
    do
        #echo $i

        var2=`PlistBuddy -c "Print Sets:$var1:Network:Global:IPv4:ServiceOrder:$i" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

        echo Key: $var2

        # PlistBuddy -c "Print NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

        PlistBuddy -c "Delete NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList:1" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

        #PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList array" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

        #PlistBuddy -c "Add NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList:1 string 192.168/16" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

        PlistBuddy -c "Set NetworkServices:$var2:Proxies:ExceptionsList:0 192.168/16" /private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
    done
fi

unset var1
unset var2

wifiutil disable-wifi
wifiutil enable-wifi
```